# Recurring payment in Paypal with codeigniter website

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am new to Codeigniter and my website needs to have recurring payments (per month after 30 days trial). I saw a lot of articles but couldn't understand anything which I can use. I also want to store user details in database. Kindly suggest any tutorial or any other help.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the sample code in Paypal and integrate with codeigniter. Check dodirectpayment method.

[DoDirectPayment documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoDirectPayment_API_Operation_NVP/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Express Checkout or with Payments Pro.

**Express Checkout**

- [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/)

**Payments Pro**

If you're using Website Payments Pro 3.0, you'd use CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile and include credit card details directly. If you're using Payments Pro 2.0 then you'll need to set it up using [PayFlow](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_guide.pdf).

My [PayPal library for CodeIgniter](http://www.binpress.com/app/paypal-adaptive-payments-pro-payflow-codeigniter-library/140) will make the API calls easy for you, and it supports all of that.

Comment: Actually I'm totally new in using this. Just created an app on the developer page and got the test credentials. What should I do next?

Comment: Express Checkout and Pro actually don't use App ID's.  All you need to do is create some sandbox accounts in there to play with and integrate those calls I listed.  All you'll need is the API username, password, and signature.

Comment: I plan to accept credit card payments and saw a lot of APIs. Which one is suitable for me?

Comment: I've always preferred a full Payments Pro account because it gives you the full freedom to build your apps and integrate things however you want.  You would use the PayFlow gateway to tie in credit cards and Express Checkout API's for PayPal payments.  My library that I linked to and those calls I mentioned are all you'd need to get up and running pretty quickly.

Comment: @Andrew Angell Am getting a message Sorry, this feature is not available at this time. When tried recurring payment using automatic billing How can i solve this